# Overview of css3 features compatible with mobile browsers?

Tags: browser, mobile, css, compatibility

I was looking for a comparison table to see which CSS3 features/selectors are compatible with mobile browsers.

I already searched at google and found this [link](http://caniuse.com/#agents=mobile). But in this link are only 4 browsers compared.

This also should be an typical overview for ppk on [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/). But on his site I only found [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html) about css on mobile browsers which handles CSS 2.1.

Does anyone of you have such an overview (or link to it)?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#agents=mobile Is already considering iOS Safari, Opera Mini, Opera Mobile and Android Browser, What other browsers you want to use with CSS3 support?

Comment: These are indeed the most used browsers for mobile devices. But I would like to know this for the more unknown browsers.

Comment: But I think in other unknown browsers you will not found CSS3 support as you asked in question. only IE9 for Windows Mobile will come with CSS3 support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this on each browser and make your own table http://tools.css3.info/selectors-test/test.html

It's for CSS selectors

Comment: This is indeed an option but I actualy was looking for an existing table. Thanks for this link but I am looking for an other answer.

Comment: Marked as answer because no other table is found so we have no choice of running this test in de mobile browsers we want to support.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using jquery mobile and a table of support is here: 
http://jquerymobile.com/original-graded-browser-matrix/

for css3: http://www.normansblog.de/demos/browser-support-checklist-css3/